# How to set a custom class to submenus in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am working on sidebar menu in a **[Custom Drupal 8 Theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming)**. I am trying to set a **`class`** of **`sidebar__menu--submenu-1`,`sidebar__menu--submenu-2`, `sidebar__menu--submenu-3`** and so on depending on the submenu's level.

So far, I was able to add the **`class` `sidebar__menu`** to the first level & **`sidebar__menu--submenu`** to all submenu's level. However, I want to add the **'class'** **`sidebar__menu--submenu-(number of the level)`** so I can style & control the sidebar better with **[CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)**.

Here it is my code menu.html.twig:

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, menu_name) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {%
    set menu_classes = [
      'sidebar__menu' ~ menu_name|clean_class,
    ]
  %}
  {%
    set submenu_classes = [
      'sidebar__menu' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '--submenu',
    ]
  %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('container mx-auto', menu_classes) }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul {{ attributes.removeClass(menu_classes).addClass(submenu_classes) }}>
    {% endif %}

    {% for item in items %}
     {%
      set classes = [
        'sidebar__item',
        item.is_expanded ? 'sidebar__item--expanded',
        item.is_collapsed ? 'sidebar__item--collapsed',
        item.in_active_trail ? 'sidebar__item--active-trail',
      ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Any help will be really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. First we set the classes:

```
{%
set submenu_classes = [
  'sidebar__menu' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '--submenu',
  'sidebar__menu--submenu-' ~ (menu_level + 1),
]
```

%}

Then using the logic like so:

```
{% if menu_level == 0 %}
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('container mx-auto', menu_classes) }}>
{% else %}
  <ul{{ attributes.removeClass(menu_classes, 'sidebar__menu--submenu-' ~ (menu_level)).addClass(submenu_classes) }}>
{% endif %}
```